# How linking too many sites from my site will affect my page rank in Google

Tags: pagerank

I run a resource and information site which provide links to sites containing specific information. E.g. it provide links to almost all paper manufacturers on the planet. These are not paid link. I don't care if any page rank is passed or not to these web sites. I want to know if it affect my site page rank and should I use nofollow attribute with all links. My site is 15 years old and has PR5.

Thanks

Comment: "links to almost all paper manufacturers on the planet" - how many is that? 100's? 1,000's? 10k? Are there so many that your site looks like a directory website?

Comment: I have about 3K links and it looks like a directory

Answer (score 2):

As long as you are linking to other reputable sites then there should be no reason to use the nofollow attribute. Many people believe that juice is lost regardless of the attribute but many believe that you actually can help your ranking by linking out because a page about 'Cats' for example linking out to 3 other reputable sites about cats.

The reason you shouldn't really need to use nofollow is that you are making the links which are relevant to the page, and the chances are these are reputable links which outbounding them should help your own rankings. If you think they are not so reputable and don't want to share the PR then simply use a nofollow. Many people use nofollow to combat spam so that they do not pass more rankings to the site than they need to, in the hope they don't spam... but as you know this doesnt stop them ;)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you stick to the nofollow tags, as long as you are not linking to authority websites. If that is not the case, continue using the dofollow links.

Page Rank is not an indication of how well your website shall rank in serps. Its mainly a measure of the dofollow sites linking to your website.